# Authorization request (add to roster) using strophe.js

Tags: xmpp, contacts, google-talk, strophe

I use [strophe.js](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs) library to send and receive XMPP messages in browser. It works fine, but only for users I already have in my contact list - roster.

I need to add someone (whose address I know) to my roster. How can I achieve this using strophe.js? This is important for me since gmail refuses sending messages to people I don't have in my roster. I'd like to get subscription: both, to be able to receive and send messages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Send `<presence to="friend@example.com" type="subscribe"/>`:

```
conn.send($pres({ to: "friend@example.com", type: "subscribe" }));
```

When your friend accepts, they should send a subscribe to you also, which you can handle by setting a Strophe handler for incoming presence with type "subscribe":

```
function on_subscription_request(stanza)
{
    if(stanza.getAttribute("type") == "subscribe" && is_friend(stanza.getAttribute("from")))
    {
        // Send a 'subscribed' notification back to accept the incoming
        // subscription request
        conn.send($pres({ to: "friend@example.com", type: "subscribed" }));
    }
    return true;
}
conn.addHandler(on_subscription_request, null, "presence", "subscribe");
```

Comment: @MattJ and whit is_friend method, can you update code with it?

Comment: @pregmatch It depends on your application. It receives a JID and should true if the user wants to accept their request, or false if they do not.

Comment: @MattJ, I understand what it does. But do you check it against roster? My question was more like how is_friend(jid) function looks like.